# How to change folder owner in Linux using Java?

Tags: java, path, permissions, file-permissions, permission-denied

I tried

```
Path path = Paths.get("/home/HP-124/Desktop/testDir2");
String newOwn = "jack";
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chown -R" +newOwn+ path);
```

and

```
File sourceFolder = new File("/home/HP-124/Desktop/testDir2");
UserPrincipal SourceFolderOwner = 
      java.nio.file.Files.getOwner(sourceFolder.toPath());
Files.setOwner(path,DestinationFolderOw);
```

**Error**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /home/p.szwajkowsk/Desktop/testDir2: Operation not permitted
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:91)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributeViews$Posix.setOwners(UnixFileAttributeViews.java:252)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributeViews$Posix.setOwner(UnixFileAttributeViews.java:274)
    at sun.nio.fs.FileOwnerAttributeViewImpl.setOwner(FileOwnerAttributeViewImpl.java:100)
    at java.nio.file.Files.setOwner(Files.java:2127)
    at com.javatutorialhq.tutorial.FilePermissions.main(FilePermissions.java:39)
```

Comment: Do you get any error when you try or does it just silently ignore? If get error please attach it.